# Is ‘round’ without an apostrophe wrong in these cases?

Tags: apostrophe

Sometimes the word *around* turns into *round*, e.g., in the following sentence:

> They were going round and round in a circle.

Shouldn’t you put an apostrophe before *round* in such cases, from the standpoint of English orthography (i.e. the rule that when you omit some part of the original word, you put an apostrophe there)?

For example, it seems to me more natural to put an apostrophe before *cause* if the word is really *because*, e.g.:

> I like coffee ’cause it makes me feel great.

Comment: "round" isn't a contracted version of "around".  Your assumption that "around" turned into "round" in this phrase may be correct, but they're two distinct words.

Comment: @MaxWilliams am I correct that _cause_ is a contracted version of _because_, though?

Comment: It can be viewed as a transatlantic variation: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/go-round-chiefly-us-also-go-around?q=go+round

Comment: You may use the apostrophe with *round* if you wish.  Most writers wouldn't.

Comment: "cause" is a word of it's own, as in "cause and effect", but "because" can be contracted to `'cause`, yes.

Comment: @Færd I'd disagree with that dictionary over whether "go round" is "chiefly US" - it's a perfectly normal thing to say in BrEng, and I think it's more common than "go around" too.

Comment: @MaxWilliams The chiefly US usage is the one in the parentheses: _go around_.

Comment: @Færd oh, yes, I beg your pardon, I misunderstood the dictionary.

Comment: @MaxWilliams It's partly the dictionary's fault. It's a bit ambiguous.

Comment: If "round and round" was good enough for 80s rockers Ratt, it's good enough for me.

Comment: "Round and round" has been idiomatic for [a long time](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22round%20and%20round%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1839,cd_max:1886&lr=lang_en).

Answer (score 4):

***Round*** in an old term and it is not generally written as 'round

***[Round vs around](http://grammarist.com/usage/around-round/)***:

> - ***Round works virtually anywhere around would work. The reverse is not true, as round has a number of definitions it doesn’t share with around***. For example, it wouldn’t work to say that the edge of a circle is around, and I wouldn’t invite you to play an around of golf.
> - ***But even though round works as a breezier alternative to around, round tends to create a casual tone, so around is usually safer in serious or formal writing***.
> - ***British writers*** in particular are wont to use round in place of around. This substitution does occur in American English, but much less often.

***[Round](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=round)*** etymology:

> - ***late 13c., from Anglo-French rounde, Old French roont*** (12c., Modern French rond), probably originally *redond, from Vulgar Latin *retundus (source also of Provençal redon, Spanish redondo, Old Italian ritondo), from Latin rotundus "like a wheel, circular, round," related to rota "wheel" (see rotary).
> - ***As an adverb from c. 1300; as a preposition from c. 1600. In many uses it is a shortened form of [around](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=around&allowed_in_frame=0)***. The French word is the source of Middle Dutch ront (Dutch rond), Middle High German runt (German rund) and similar Germanic words.